# split float in Java Android

Tags: java, android

I have a number like 2.75. I want to split this number into two other floats. Here is an example of what I am searching for:

```
value = 2.75 
value2 = 2.0
value3 = 0.75
```

I need them in my algorithm, so how could I implement this? I found `split()` but it returns string. I need floats or integer at least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also try this

```
double value = 2.75;
double fraction=value%1;//Give you 0.75 as remainder 
int integer=(int)value;//give you 2 fraction part will be removed
```

***NOTE:***
As result may very in `fraction` due to use of `double`.You better use

```
float fraction=(float) (value%1);
```

if `fractional` part is big.

Answer (score 6):

You could cast

```
float value = 2.75f;
int valueTruncated = (int) value;
float value2 = valueTruncated;
float value3 = value - value2;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use split():

```
double value = 2.75;
/* This won't work */// String[] strValues = String.valueOf(value).split(".");
String[] strValues = String.valueOf(value).split("\\.");
double val1 = Double.parseDouble(strValues[0]); // 2.0
double val2 = Double.parseDouble(strValues[1]); // 0.75
```

Comment: And what if decimals are splits by ","? Hello ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Comment: Well @Stan, I'm not sure about "," but the question asks for values containing ".". I'm sorry I'm not very pro in Java yet, but I'm always eager to learn...

Comment: I just wanna say that in different locales the comma sign is different. I mean the "splitter char" between decimals and float parts. For example in US its "," while in Germany its "." meaning that code has to work locale independently. Your code gonna crash running with US locale since there will be no dots and thus you'll get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Ah okay cool, thanks for pointing that out. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2):

if the input is 59.38
result is 
n1 = 59
n2 = 38
this is what I came up with:

```
    int n1, n2 = 0; 
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    double input = scan.nextDouble();

    n1 = (int) input;
    n2 = (int) Math.round((input % 1) * 100);
```